# Why every regular monomorphism is a monomorphism?

Tags: category-theory, monomorphisms

I read in section 7.57 of Adameck's book (*Abstract and Concrete Categories The Joy of Cats*) that due to the uniqueness requirement in the definition of equalizer, every *regular* monomorphism must be a monomorphism. I see that in category theory, it is a usual practice to utilize the **uniqueness** property to prove **equality** theorems, but I could not use it here to prove that every regular monomorphism is left-cancellable.

Comment: Could you please refresh my memory: What is a regular monomorphism?

Comment: @Arthur A regular monomorphism is a map which is an equaliser of two maps.

Comment: Hi, sure. According the book cited above, a regular monomorphism in a category is any morphisms that is an equalizer of some pair of morphisms in that category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $k:K\rightarrow X$ is a regular monomorphism, arising as the equalizer of two morphisms $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$.

We want to show that $k$ is leftcancelable, hence a monomorphism. To this end let $t,s: T \rightarrow K$ be two morphisms satisfying $kt=ks$. Call this composite $x:T\rightarrow X$. Now since $fx=fkt=gkt=gx$ the universal property of the equalizer $k$ yields a unique morphism $y:T\rightarrow K$ satisfying $x=ky$. But both $t$ and $s$ have this property, so the uniqueness in the universal property implies $t=y=s$.

Comment: I appreciate for your answer and attention. A question: we supposed that *k* is an equalizer of *f* and *g*, but how do we know that *x* is also an equalizer for those two morphisms?

Comment: We know that $fk=gk$ by assumption. Hence $fkt=gkt$ and plugging in the definition of $x$ we have $fx=gx$. Hence $x$ *equalizes* $f$ and $g$. Be aware that the term *equalizer* is reserved for the universal morphism with this property (in this case $k$).

Comment: Hi again, thank you very much. That was the key point. Now I understand what happens.

Comment: You are welcome :) Feel free to accept my answer to close this question…